# Парсинг телефона с мобильной версии авито

Tags: python, парсер

Пытаюсь получить телефон из мобильной версии, там он в тексте, но для его получения нужно нажать "*Показать номер*". Вот [пример](https://m.avito.ru/chita/tovary_dlya_detey_i_igrushki/kupi_slona_696014781)

По нажатию на "*Показать номер*" уходит запрос типа
`https://m.avito.ru/chita/tovary_dlya_detey_i_igrushki/kupi_slona_696014781/phone/fae634b4155194d4b5f7746ce08ecc86?async`, но если попытаться вставить в новую вкладку или вытащить запросом номер, то - `{"error":"пожалуйста, обновите страницу"}`

```
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.session()
resp = session.get(url, headers=headers)

html = fromstring(resp.content)
href = html.xpath(".//*[@class='clearfix']/a[1]/@href")[0]

url = urljoin(resp.url, href+'?async')
resp = session.get(url)

html = fromstring(resp.content)
phone = html.xpath(".//*[@class='clearfix']/a[1]/span/text()")[0]
```

Если убрать `?async`, то он просто рендерит страничку с объявлением.

Подскажите, как вытащить?

Comment: Стоит взглянуть на пользовательское соглашение Avito: [agreement](https://www.avito.ru/info/polzovatelskoe_soglashenie). А конкретно пункт 5.3. Своими действиями вы нарушаете его. Да и без всяких соглашений было бы совсем неприятно, что кто-то вытащит телефон из объявления и использует его в своих целях. А то потом сидишь и гадаешь, откуда это спам приходит?

Comment: Вопрос направлен на явный обход пользовательского соглашения, и скорее всего на сбор персональной информации участников стороннего сайта. Не считаю, что таким вопросам место на нашем сайте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что в таких случаях нужно смотреть -  не проверяется ли [HTTP_REFERER](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer). И догадка оказывается правильной:

```
wget -o /dev/null -O - \
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36" \
--referer="https://m.avito.ru/chita/tovary_dlya_detey_i_igrushki/kupi_slona_696014781" \
"https://m.avito.ru/chita/tovary_dlya_detey_i_igrushki/kupi_slona_696014781/phone/fae634b4155194d4b5f7746ce08ecc86?async"
```

Вуаля:

```
{"phone":"8 914 456-89-88"}
```

Соответственно, надо просто добавить в `headers` поле `Referer` с адресом нужной страницы.

Comment: Мне кажется, не стоит помогать спамерам.

Comment: @VladD, формальности соблюдены и лучи поноса отправлены. Но всё равно ведь нароет...

Comment: @VladD: 1- мы не знаем является ли автор вопроса спамером. Нарушение пользовательского соглашения на совести автора вопроса, человек, который отвечает на вопрос, не адвокат и легальный совет не  может и не должен давать. 2- Если вся защита (если это можно защитой назвать) это наличие Referer http заголовка, то не нужно подобным сайтам давать свои данные --  неизбежно  такие данные будут собраны в не зависимости от наличия/отсутствия ответов на SO.

Comment: @jfs: Если автор вопроса спрашивает, как взломать дешёвый замок, а мы пускаемся в рассуждения, что если защита квартиры построена на таком дешёвом замке, то пусть дурака-хозяина лучше обворуют — думаю, нас можно после этого назвать негодяями. Хотя да, формально мы ничего плохого не совершили.

Comment: @jfs: Формально, да, мы [не знаем, зачем автору вопроса бот для сбора телефонов](https://www.google.com/search?q=вот+на+этом+невысказанном+предположении).

Comment: @VladD: Аналогия неверна. При чём здесь квартиры? Сайт это сайт (я это слово понимаю, вы (я надеюсь) это слово понимаете -- используйте адекватный язык).

Comment: @jfs: Да, я понимаю слово «сайт». Мне кажется самоочевидным, что ТС хочет собрать много телефонов, и кажется очевидным, что он делает это на продажу. И кажется очевидным, что его планы если не преступны формально, то будут причинять неудобство честным людям, которые вовсе не соглашались на публикацию своего телефона в открытом виде. Да, формально я не могу этого доказать.

Comment: @jfs: Я считаю, что вы для усиления собственной позиции должны бы опубликовать свой телефон в открытый доступ.

Comment: @VladD: 1- я явно сказал: *"не нужно подобным сайтам давать свои данные"* где вы здесь увидели призыв опубликовать свой телефон в открытый доступ? Я не понимаю, честно, серьёзный вопрос, где в этой фразе вы увидели подобное желание? 2- мне это НЕ кажется самочевидным, потому что не вижу смысла (по крайней мере лет 10-20 назад были широко доступны телефонные базы и даже сайты существовали для поиска -- если нужны номера с именами из паспорта, то легко было получить доступ к миллионам записям) -- ни к чему скрести какой-то сайт, чтобы меньше и хуже информацию получить с большими усилиями

Comment: @jfs: Мне сложно без аналогий объяснить, почему совет «не нужно подобным сайтам давать свои данные» крайне неэтичен. Не понимаю, почему вы не видите этого сами. Вы смещаете вину за разглашение персональной информации с преступника на потерпевшую сторону. Аналогию с изнасилованием придумайте сами.

Comment: @VladD: Если вы добавление Referer http заголовка с изнасилованием увязываете (попробуйте вслух прочитать это -- может поможет абсурдность осознать) , то я позволю несколько в сторону замечание сделать: логическим последствием развития вашей логики является сжигание ведьм на кострах (я надеюсь вы в ведьм не верите и по другим причинам считаете что нехорошо людей сжигать) или современный аналог: газовые камеры для части населения, не соответствующего некоторым высоким моральным стандартам, при молчаливом одобрении большинством. Это много раз в истории уже повторялась-такова природа многих людей

Comment: Да ну что сразу спам. Лучик я послал с явным `if(isspam())` на всякий случай :) Доводилось, например, писать для личных целей мониторинг объявлений по ключевым словам, чтобы не упустить хорошую и редкую штуку, и чтобы сразу текст с телефоном в почту падал. А что касается "пункта 5.3" (совершенно идиотского и исключающего саму возможность пользоваться авито в принципе) - это тема для отдельного обсуждения...