# Нажатие на элемент anglesharp

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Как нажать на элемент, а потом спарсить после нажатия?
Я написал, но у меня почему-то ничего не меняется

```
var config =
        new Configuration()
        .WithRequesters()
        .WithDefaultLoader()
        .WithCss()
        .WithJavaScript();
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
var document = await context.OpenAsync(site);

foreach (IHtmlElement element in document.QuerySelectorAll("div.clearfix>a"))
{
    element.DoClick();
    // element.DoClick();
    Console.WriteLine(element.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: что вы имеете в виду под словом нажать? правильнее судя по всему получить ссылку, и по ней уже получить документ и распарсить его.

Comment: когда на нее нажимаешь содержимое в ней меняется, и вот то что изменилось получить

Comment: А адрес меняется?

Comment: Да, меняется и без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: кто мешает перейти по адресу, который вам нужен?

Comment: То что при переходе по адрессу контент не изменится, поэтому надо как-то с симулировать нажатие

Comment: так вы определитесь, меняется адрес или нет! Если адрес не меняется ищите скрытые поля, куки, которые меняются!

Comment: Щас объясню адрес меняется в случае нажатие на елемент, но если перейти по ссылке то ничего не происходит

Comment: смотрите что кроме адреса меняется!

Comment: Меняется еще и тег span, в нем становится больше инфы

Comment: Но если переходить по ссылки он не меняется

Comment: не забывайте про постбэк.

Comment: Тут два выхода вижу, либо симулировать нажатие, либо запускать js который возвращает полную информацию, но js я плохо понимаю, поэтому подумал что можно симулировать нажатие

Comment: Есть еще один момент как вывести данные послать HTTP referer и получить данные, только я не знаю как это делается

Comment: Вообще это парсинг авито.

Comment: А идею с рефером я взял отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541880/Парсинг-телефона-с-мобильной-версии-авито?rq=1

Comment: Все я сделал, вопрос можно закрыввать

Comment: Напишите хоть ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var Requester = new HttpRequester();
        Requester.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36";
        var configuration = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader(_ => _.IsResourceLoadingEnabled = true, new[] { Requester });
        var _context = BrowsingContext.New(configuration);
        var _document = _context.OpenAsync("strnica kotoraya nugna");

        var domParser = new HtmlParser();
        var result = domParser.Parse(_document.Result.ToHtml());

        var items = result.QuerySelectorAll($"div>a").Where(item => item.Attributes[$"href"] != null);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
           if(item.Attributes[$"href"].Value.ToString().StartsWith("tel:"))
            Console.WriteLine(item.Attributes[$"href"].Value.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Там даже нажимать ничего не надо, в самой ссылке записан телефончик

Comment: Теперь думаю можно точно закрывать